# Multiple SeekBars listener

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

I have multiple seekbar on the same view :

```
barheures = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.barheures); // make seekbar object
        barheures.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // set seekbar listener.
        // since we are using this class as the listener the class is "this"
        barminutes = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.barminutes);
        barminutes.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

And here is the listener:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("", "" + bar);
    textMinutes.setText("" + progress + "Minute(s)" );
    textHours.setText("" + progress + "Heure(s)" );
}
```

I wanna make something different if the first OR the second bar have moved into the same listener (is it the good practice?), but how to?? Here I have the app that don't do what I want

Answer (score 21):

Now then you have 2 seekbars with the following ids:

1. barheures - its id: R.id.barheures
2. barminutes - its id: R.id.barminutes

Now in the onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) method, Do the following:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("", "" + bar);

    switch (bar.getId()) {

    case R.id.barheures:
        textHours.setText("" + progress + "Heure(s)");
        break;

    case R.id.barminutes:
        textMinutes.setText("" + progress + "Minute(s)");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of comparing resource ids, you can also just check the SeekBar object for equality. Example:

```
private SeekBar bar1;
private SeekBar bar2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    bar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar1);
    bar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar2);

    ...
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    if (bar.equals(bar1))
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (bar.equals(bar2))
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

I prefer doing it this way because then you only ever reference the id of each SeekBar resource once (in your `onCreate`).